# retrive two tables from a single query in pyoDBC

Tags: python, pyodbc

first question here since years.
i have a simple query with a try catch:

```
query = f"""
BEGIN TRY
    **a query that can give an error
    with structure:
    insert into TABLE
    primary key
    foreign key ---> that has no match on other tables, giving error**

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
END CATCH
"""
cursor.execute(query)

AAAAArow = cursor.fetchall()
```

the problem is thi gives as output two tables if the first query fails: an empty window (in SMSS) that fetchall gives as a empty list, and a table with one line with the error detail.
but fetchall gives as output only the empty list of the first query, and not the second one. how can i fetch two different tables that comes from a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of a more expert collegue a solution has been found:

```
query = f"""
BEGIN TRY
    **a query that can give an error
    with structure:
    insert into TABLE
    primary key
    foreign key ---> that has no match on other tables, giving error**

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
END CATCH
"""
cursor.execute(query)
AAAAArow = cursor.fetchall()
```

simply add:

```
NEXT = cursor.nextset()
AAAAArow2 = cursor.fetchone()
```

NEXT is a boolean variable that has the value TRUE if there is another table to read, false if not. if is true it automatically changes the reading table. So by doing a second fetchone() the output will be the second table and go on